# Should I choose Random Forest regressor or classifier?

Tags: python, random-forest

I fit a dataset with a binary target class by the random forest. In python, I can do it either by randomforestclassifier or randomforestregressor.

I can get the classification directly from randomforestclassifier or I could run randomforestregressor first and get back a set of estimated scores (continuous value). Then I can find a cutoff value to derive the predicted classes out of the set of scores. Both methods can achieve the same goal (i.e. predict the classes for the test data).

Also I can observe that

```
randomforestclassifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
```

is different from

```
randomforestregressor.predict(X_test)
```

So I just wanna confirm that both methods are valid and then which one is better in random forest application?

Comment: My immediate reaction is you should use the classifier because this is precisely what it is built for, but I'm not 100% sure it makes much difference.  Using the regressor would be like using linear regression instead of logistic regression - it works, but not as well in many situations.  I might get around to a proper answer but not for a day or so.

Answer (score 19):

**Use the Classifier. No, they are not both valid.**

First, I really encourage you to read yourself into the topic of Regression vs Classification. Because using ML without knowing anything about it will give you wrong results which you  won't realize. And that's quite dangerous... (*it's a little bit like asking which way around you should hold your gun or if it doesn't matter*)

Whether you use a classifier or a regressor **only** depends on the kind of problem you are solving. You have a binary **classification** problem, so use the classifier.

> I could run randomforestregressor first and get back a set of estimated probabilities.

**NO.** You don't get probabilities from regression. It just tries to "extrapolate" the values you give (in this case only 0 and 1). This means values above 1 or below 0 are *perfectly valid* as a regression output as it does not expect only two discrete values as output (that's called *classification*!) but continuous values.

If you want to have the "probabilities" (*be aware that these don't have to be well calibrated probabilities*) for a certain point to belong to a certain class, train a classifier (so it learns to *classify* the data) and then use .predict_proba(), which then predicts the probability.

Just to mention it here: .predict vs .predict_proba (for a classifier!)
.predict just takes the .predict_proba output and changes everything to 0 below a certain threshold (usually 0.5) respectively to 1 above that threshold.

Remark: *sure, internally, they are the very same except from the "last layer" etc.! Still, see them (or better the problem they are solving) as completely different!*

Comment: It does not extrapolate beyond 1 or below 0. It is a random Forest. It can't see beyond  domain value of the data (It is incapable of predicting a straight line beyond what is present in the data itself). I ran a 500k dataset and found that it stays within 0 and 1

Comment: This is in fact true for a _pure_ random forest, I agree. My answer is maybe more generally targeted towards classifier vs regressor. However, you are correct on a pure random forest.